# Define a abstract commutative function in Python (SymPy)

Tags: python, sympy

Suppose I define a function `H`

```
from sympy import Function
H = Function('H')
```

How could I make `H` commutative in its arguments such that

```
>>> H(x,y)+H(y,x)
2*H(x,y)
```

where `x` and `y` are symbols.

My current workaround is to define an additional function `H1`, which returns `H(x,y)` by first ordering the arguments. Then Python does the rest:

```
>>> H1(x,y)+H1(y,x)
2*H(x,y)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define an extension to SymPy’s `Function` class to add this property, similar to the example [here](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/index.html):

```
class H(sympy.Function):
    nargs = (2,)

    @classmethod
    def eval(cls, arg1, arg2):
        if order(arg1,arg2):
            return H(arg2,arg1)
```

This swaps the arguments if `order(arg1,arg2)` is `True`, otherwise it leaves them as it is. This way, if `H` is called with identical but swapped arguments, the output should always be identical.

Now, we only need a good `order` function. The easiest way is to convert the respective symbols to strings and compare them:

```
order = lambda arg1,arg2: str(arg1)>str(arg2)
```

However, this may not work as intended if the arguments are equivalent but not identical in their symbolic representation. Here is a more sophisticated version of `order` that takes this into account (as far as possible) by using SymPy’s `equals` (which is more thorough than `==` as it uses simplifying):

```
def order(arg1,arg2):
    if arg1.equals(arg2):
        return False
    else:
        return str(arg1)>str(arg2)
```

Be aware that `order` will be executed pretty often and it may therefore be desirable to keep it fast and simple.

The function `H` now has your desired properties:

```
from sympy.abc import a,b
print( H(a,b) + H(b,a) )
# 2*H(a, b)
```